# Transitions between batch files and changing from batch1 to batch2

Tags: loops, echo, call, transition, goto

I am experimenting a bit for fun
I want a matrix-like transition between my call batch1.bat and my call batch2.bat
so I have this command

```
echo off
color 0a
:start
echo %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% 
goto start
call batch2.bat
```

and I want to set it to loop for 3 seconds before moving on to batch2.bat
but I am new and I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is a difficult task for a complete total novice like me but I figured how to make it loop for 3 seconds before doing the (call batch2.bat)

```
  @echo off
  color 0a
  set /a count=0
  :top
  echo %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% %random% 
  set /a count+=1
  if %count%==300 (
  goto end
  ) else (
  goto top
  )
  :end
  cls
  echo u did it
  pause
  call "tic tac toe.bat"
```

note that I used quotation marks on the call because if I didn't the game transition would just crash and I figured that it 100 counts of the script is about a second so I put 300 ... I feel proud of myself :)